# Why does SONET need atomic clock but T-carrier does not?

Tags: layer2, layer1, internet, fiber, telephony

SONET and T-carrier are both synchronous TDM.

But T-carrier does not use atomic clock. Why does SONET?

Is it because SONET does not use buffer? But how does it prevent bit loss if there is no buffering?

Comment: SONET/SDH end-stations, like routers or PSTN switches, can be clocked from the line/network.  I believe you only need an accurate clock if you are a node able to add/drop/mux SONET channels among different circuits.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

SONET, or rather the *synchronous digital hierarchy* it's running on, requires very tight clock coupling across the whole structure. In order to stay within the sub-millisecond tolerances, there's no other way than with atomic clocks.

Sharing a central clock wouldn't work due to the inherent limitation of the speed of light, which covers just 300 km in one ms (or only 200 km over fiber) - minus processing overhead, the hierarchy would need to be very limited in geographic size.

T-carrier uses a much simpler master-slave clocking, so there's no requirements for atomic clocks.